# How to access packages in vendor directory

Tags: php, cakephp, autoload

Calling any package from the `vendor` directory structure within any CakePHP controller works, as the `composer` set up everything correctly. For example this MCVE from https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php#quick-examples

```
$swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
try {
    $swissNumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($swissNumberStr, "CH");
    var_dump($swissNumberProto);
} catch (\libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

When I run the equal code directly in `webroot/sample.php` so it fails :

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
> 'libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil' not found in ...sample.php

**My question:**

What do I have to do outside the CakePHP *world* so I can use the packages in the `vendor` directory structure?

Comment: This only works because they installed it via composer: [`composer require giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php`](https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php#installation). The vendor folder is the one composer stores your dependancies. Maybe have a look in the project and see how it is easy to use: https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Check my answer, I think, I found the solution. It was in the end simpler than I thought. Hopefully it helps others with the same problem.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap , then use namespace to include classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was now looking around and I saw in the `vendor` directory the file `autoload.php` and I gave it a try.

The solution is:

Outside the CakePHP *world* I have only to include this `autoload.php`:

```
include( __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
```

Then all packages in the `vendor` directory became available.